# add firstname to session data with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am trying to figure out how to add the users firstname to the session data. currently i am only able to add email and not even sure how i did that. any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

here is my model for adding a new user:

```
public function add_user($key){
        $this->db->where('key', $key);
        $temp_user = $this->db->get('temp_users');

        if($temp_user){
            $row = $temp_user->row();
            $data = array(
                'firstname' => $row->firstname,
                'email' => $row->email,
                'password' => $row->password
            );

            $did_add_user = $this->db->insert('users', $data);
        }
        if($did_add_user){
            $this->db->where('key', $key);
            $this->db->delete('temp_users');
            return $data['email'];
        } return false;

    }
```

Here is my controller info(i am currently adding a static value 'kyle' to session data for firstname).I want to add the actual users firstname taken from database:

```
public function register_user($key){
        $this->load->model('model_users');
        if($this->model_users->is_key_valid($key)){
            if($newemail = $this->model_users->add_user($key)){
                $data = array(
                    'firstname' => "kyle",
                    'email' =>  $newemail,
                    'is_logged_in' => 1
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                redirect('login/members');
            }else echo "Failed to add user, please try again.";
        }else echo "invalid Key";
    }
```

Here is my view:

## Members Page

### session->userdata('email'); echo $session_id; ?>

session->all_userdata(); print_r($session_info); ?>

Here is what the session array prints out:

```
Array ( [session_id] => 4fb01d348ba495ef010fe07415713167 [ip_address] => blah.blah.blah [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.99 Safari/537.36 [last_activity] => 1421942397 [user_data] => [firstname] => kyle [email] => freeride5567@yahoo.com [is_logged_in] => 1 )
```

Comment: I was able to get the session array to hold the firstname. now i am stuck on how to display in view. new session array:

Comment: Array ( [session_id] => c7ea9d37859602c2d3190dce14c120bd [ip_address] => 654.45.45 [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.99 Safari/537.36 [last_activity] => 1421943335 [user_data] => [firstname] => kyle [email] => Array ( [firstname] => Eric [email] => freeride5567@yahoo.com [password] => 894027e71b85d60bcc5b0dbe6e83f1f6 ) [is_logged_in] => 1 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check codeigniter documentation:

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

```
#1 
public function add_user($key){

    $this->db->where('key', $key);
    $temp_user = $this->db->get('temp_users');

    if($temp_user){
        $row = $temp_user->row();
        $data = array(
            'firstname' => $row->firstname,
            'email' => $row->email,
            'password' => $row->password
        );

       $this->db->insert('users', $data);

       if( $this->db->affected_rows() > 0 ){

          $this->db->where('key', $key);
          $this->db->delete('temp_users');

          return (object)array(
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'firstname' => $data['firstname']  
         );
      } 

    }

    return false;

}

public function register_user($key){
    $this->load->model('model_users');
    if($this->model_users->is_key_valid($key)){
        if($res = $this->model_users->add_user($key)){ //here
            $data = array(
                'firstname' => $res->firstname,
                'email' =>  $res->email,
                'is_logged_in' => 1
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('login/members');
        }else echo "Failed to add user, please try again.";
    }else echo "invalid Key";
}
```

Comment: you could move the session in your model or in your model: soon adding return the firstname

Comment: thank you, but that just caused a bunch of errors. Unknown column 'is_logged_in' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `users` (`firstname`, `email`, `is_logged_in`) VALUES (NULL, 'freeride5567@yahoo.com', 1)

Filename: /home4/travism2/public_html/HELLER-RECIPES/models/model_users.php

Comment: How would i echo this out in the view? sorry i am still learning and new.

Comment: I was able to figure it out how to echo out in view, thank you for your answer. Much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

For getting firstname via sessions, tonoslfx's answer is correct.

i.e.: Storing the data in session as an array:

```
return array(
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'firstname' => $data['firstname']  
);
```

As per the further  discussion in comments and chat, the following was the solution as to how to get firstname in session when the user logs in after registration:

In controller:

```
public function login_validation(){ 
    $this->load->library('form_validation'); 

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|xss_clean|callback_validate_credentials'); 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5|trim'); 

    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    if($this->form_validation->run()){ 
        if($this->model_users->can_log_in($email, $password)) {
            $userData = $this->model_users->getDataForSession($email);
            $data = array(
                "firstname" => $userData->firstname;
                "email" => $email,
                "is_logged_in" => 1
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('login/members'); 
        }
    } 
    else{ 
        $this->signin(); 
    } 
}
```

In the 'model_users' model, use this:

```
public function can_log_in($email, $password){
    $this->db->where('email', $email); 
    $this->db->where('password', md5($password)); 
    $query = $this->db->get('users'); 
    if($query->num_rows() == 1){ 
        return true; 
    } 
    else { 
        return false; 
    } 
}

public function getDataForSession($email){
    $this->db->select('firstname');
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    return $this->db->get('users')->row();
}
```

Comment: I already have a session named is_logged_in that i use to make sure the user is logged in before accessing certain pages.

Comment: I was getting all sessions so i could see the array and know what data i actually had available. testing purposes. once i can figure out how to get specific data from the session i will change for production

Comment: In the output of print_r that you have shared, I can see 'firstname' as kyle just before the email.Can you briefly explain what is the issue you want to resolve?

Comment: Have edited the answer. Check to see if that helps :)

Comment: @tonoslfx had the correct answer i was looking for. thanks for helping out.

Comment: Just realized that this only sends the session data to the register user function not the actuall members page. so when the user logs out after activating their account and log back in it goes to the members page that no longer has any of the session data. I have no idea how to tackle this. I am thinking i need to create a unique session everytime the user logs in that grabs their firstname and email address from the database. any thoughts?

Comment: When the user logs out, the sessions are destroyed, which is expected. You've got it right as per the idea you just commented. You should fetch 'firstname' and 'email' from database just after authenticating the user, and before redirecting the user to the members page. Fetch it, create a session and name it anything you like. Reply back in case you have any other doubt! :)

Comment: how do i grab the unique users firstname and email from database without grabbing all the users? I am stuck on how grab that specific usesr info when logging in and then turning it into a session

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69411/discussion-between-harry33166-and-travis-michael-heller).